# Joda-Time DateFormatter to display milliseconds if nonzero

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

Using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), I want to display a list of dates that may or may not have milliseconds on them.  If a certain entry has milliseconds, then it should be displayed like `yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`.  If it doesn't have the millis, I need it displayed as `yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss`.

I suppose the general question is: Is there a way to describe an optional format string parameter?

(I'd like to avoid refactoring all of the places that I use formatters since this is a large code base.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no optional patterns.  However, I think you may be overthinking your problem.

```
// Sample variable name - you'd probably name this better.
public static DateTimeFormat LONG_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.forPattern("yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

// Note that this could easily take a DateTime directly if that's what you've got.
// Hint hint non-null valid date hint hint.
public static String formatAndChopEmptyMilliseconds(final Date nonNullValidDate) {
    final String formattedString = LONG_FORMATTER.print(new DateTime(nonNullValidDate));
    return formattedString.endsWith(".000") ? formattedString.substring(0, formattedString.length() - 4) : formattedString;
}
```

The length may not be exactly right for the substring (untested code), but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks.  I extended `DateTimeFormatter` to nest this logic right there, and it works pretty well.  I can still pass around my formatter and get the results I want.  (And I guess I was overthinking it.  Heh.)